# Saving primary and foreign keytables at once in EF6

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have primary table and 3 foreign key tables and trying to save all at once. Some time some OK and some time giving error.

```
 public partial class meeting_abstract
 {
     public int meeting_abstract_id { get; set; }
     public int meeting_id { get; set; }
     public System.DateTime submission_date { get; set; }


     public virtual ICollection<abstract_author> abstract_author { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<abstract_category> abstract_category { get; set; }
     public virtual ICollection<abstract_questions> abstract_questions { get; set; }
}



var meeting_abstract = new meeting_abstract();
 meeting_abstract.meeting_id = meetingAbstract.Meeting.meeting_id;
 meeting_abstract.submission_date = DateTime.Now;

 meeting_abstract.abstract_questions = new Collection<abstract_questions>();
 var abstractQuestion = new abstract_questions();
  abstractQuestion.meeting_question_id = Convert.ToInt32(meetingAbstract.AbstractTitleInEnglishId);
  abstractQuestion.abstract_question_answer = meetingAbstract.AbstractTitleInEnglishText;
  meeting_abstract.abstract_questions.Add(abstractQuestion);
  abstractQuestion = new abstract_questions();
  abstractQuestion.meeting_question_id = Convert.ToInt32(meetingAbstract.AbstractTitleInLanguageId);
  abstractQuestion.abstract_question_answer = meetingAbstract.AbstractTitleInLanguageText;
  meeting_abstract.abstract_questions.Add(abstractQuestion);

  meeting_abstract.abstract_author.Add(meetingAbstract.primaryAuthor);

 var abstractCategory = new abstract_category()
  {
       meeting_category_id = meetingCategory.meeting_category_id
    };
    meeting_abstract.abstract_category = new Collection<abstract_category>();
    meeting_abstract.abstract_category.Add(abstractCategory);

 _abstractRewriteEntities.meeting_abstract.Add(meeting_abstract);
  _abstractRewriteEntities.SaveChanges();
```

Whats wrong here? I cannot save all together?

Comment: What error does it give? How are you adding these to the context?

Comment: Message = "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_abstract_category_1'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.abstract_category'. The duplicate key value is (0).\r\nThe statement has been terminated."

Comment: Does it really say `0` as duplicate key value?? Is it an identity column?

Answer (score 0):

When adding more than one item, with a property defined as the identity, you will need to give those entities a unique key even though it will ultimately be set by the db. We do this in our project by defining a partial class for that entity, and in `OnCreated` making sure they have a unique value for their identity.
For example:

```
public partial class abstract_questions
    {
        private static int _newIdentity = 0;

        partial void OnCreated()
        {
            //Set an identity value so when two new entities
                    // are created Entity Framework doesn't whinge 
                    // on the server because of duplicate keys
            _newIdentity = _newIdentity - 1;

                    // Set whatever is defined as the identity/pk property
            this.Id = _newIdentity;
        }
```